# Oracle drop user check

Tags: sql, oracle11gr2

DB: Oracle11gR2

OS: Linux

I want to drop USER1 Oracle user which is already locked for few weeks now.

I can run `"drop user USER1 cascade;"` to drop user but before dropping want to confirm nobody else is using or used objects after user was locked.

1. How to verify in Oracle that nobody is accessing or have accessed USER1 objects in last month or so?
2. Is there a db query/view available which we can use to make sure it's safe to run DROP command?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you would have enabled auditing of accesses on the various objects when you locked the account and left that in place for however long you would need to feel comfortable.  A month may be sufficient but there may be quarterly or annual processes as well that you need to consider.

Assuming that you didn't enable auditing at the time and don't want to enable auditing now and wait another month, there are less complete approaches that you may be able to use (with the understanding that those approaches are going to provide less certainty).

- You can query `v$segment_statistics` joined to `v$statname` to look at a variety of statistics about the table segments.  "db block gets" and "consistent gets", for example, would show you how many times some process did a current or a consistent read on a block in a table.  But it won't tell you what did the reads-- the background job that gathers statistics, for example, might read the data from the table.  Those tables should accumulate data since the database was last restarted which may be significantly longer or shorter than the time period that you're interested in.  You can get a [list of the available statistics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/stats002.htm#i26158) in the Oracle documentation to fine-tune exactly what you want to look for.
- You can query `dba_hist_seg_stat` rather than `v$segment_statistics`.  That will break out the statistics by time period so it will tell you when reads and writes happened.  But it won't tell you who did them.  That also requires that you be licensed to use the AWR (otherwise querying the table may violate your license and create an issue if you're ever audited).
- You can look at `dba_dependencies` to see if any objects depend on objects owned by the user in question.  But that will only work for stored objects (views, procedures, etc.).  It won't capture information about SQL statements that are submitted from applications or ad hoc queries issued by users.

If you don't want to enable auditing and wait an appropriate period, you may be better served revoking privileges on the `user1` objects from whatever roles/ users have them rather than dropping the objects outright.  That way if something blows up from lack of privileges, it's relatively easy to restore the privilege without getting the object(s) back from backup.  You could also create a trigger on a permission denied error that told you where the request was coming from.

Comment: thank you for the wonderful details and it indeed gave me various options to go for, really liked all recommendations and will be looking to implement atleast two before dropping user. I'm also renaming tables and leaving it for sometime before drop.